# PHP: I can't insert data into MYSQL DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a litle web app that allow me to insert an athlete & coach information into mysql database , coach data( data pelatih/ data penguji) are inserted to a table called tb_admin, it contain administrator data and coach data,,

the page that process CRUD athlete data are working perfectly but the page that process coach data can't insert data into database 
(nb : both page , athlete and coach page are coded in same style )

```
    <?php
session_start(); /* memulai session */
include 'koneksi.php'; /* membuat koneksi ke database */
if (!empty($_SESSION['LOGIN_username']) and $_SESSION['LOGIN_usertype']=='admin') 
    {

# Terpilih jenis kelamin
if($_POST['cmb_jeniskelamin']=="laki-laki") { $jeniskelamin1    = " selected"; }
else if($_POST['cmb_jeniskelamin']=="perempuan") { $jeniskelamin2   = " selected"; }


if(!empty($_POST['cmd_simpan'])){
    if(empty($_POST['txt_nama']) OR 
       empty($_POST['txt_alamat']) OR 
       empty($_POST['txt_username']) OR 
       empty($_POST['txt_password']) OR 
       empty($_POST['txt_password1'])){
           echo "<script>window.alert('Kolom bertanda \'harus diisi\' tidak boleh kosong.');</script>";
    }else {
        if ($_POST['txt_password']!=$_POST['txt_password1']){
            echo "<script>window.alert('Kolom Password Baru dan Password Baru (ulangi) harus sama.');</script>";
    }else{
        if($_POST['txt_action']=='new'){
            $q="insert into tb_admin(id_admin, nama, alamat, jenis_kelamin, satlat, username, password) values(NULL, '".$_POST['txt_nama']."', '".$_POST['txt_alamat']."', '".$_POST['cmb_jeniskelamin']."', '".$_POST['txt_satlat']."', '".$_POST['txt_username']."', '".md5($_POST['txt_password'])."')";
            mysql_query($q);
        }

        exit("<script>location.href='?hal=data_penguji';</script>");
    }
}

}

if($_GET['action']=='delete' and (int)$_GET['id']>0){
    $str->id=(int)$_GET['id'];
    $q=mysql_query("delete from tb_admin where id_admin='".$str->id."'");
    exit("<script>location.href='?hal=data_penguji';</script>");
}


?>

    <div style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;padding:3px ">
    <div style="font-size:18px;padding:10px 0 10px 0 ">TAMBAH DATA PENGUJI</div>
    <form action="" name="" method="post">
    <input name="txt_action" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $str->action;?>">
    <input name="txt_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $str->id;?>">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="0" class="tabel_reg">
      <tr>
        <td width="120"valign="top">Nama</td>
        <td><input name="txt_nama" type="text" size="40" value=""> <em>harus diisi</em></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alamat</td>
        <td><input name="txt_alamat" type="text" size="40" value=""> <em>harus diisi</em></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Jenis Kelamin</td>
        <td><select name="cmb_jeniskelamin">

    <option value="laki-laki"  <?php echo $jeniskelamin1; ?>> laki-laki </option>
    <option value="perempuan"   <?php echo $jeniskelamin2; ?>> perempuan </option>
    </select>  
     <em>harus diisi</em></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Satlat</td>
        <td><input name="txt_satlat" type="text" size="40" value=""> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td><input name="txt_username" type="text" size="5" value=""><em>harus diisi</em></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input name="txt_password" type="password" size="5" value=""><em>harus diisi</em></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password (Ulangi)</td>
        <td><input name="txt_password1" type="password" size="5" value=""><em>harus diisi</em></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="cmd_simpan" type="submit" value="Simpan"> <input name="cmd_batal" type="button" onClick="location.href='?hal=data_penguji';" value="Batal"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>


    </div>

<?php       
}
else { 
    echo "<script>alert('untuk mengakses page ini anda harus login terlebih dahulu');</script>";
            echo "<script>windows.location='?hal=front';</script>";

            }
        ?>
```

i think the part that contain error,are the part that contain mysql_query ,

```
if($_POST['txt_action']=='new'){
                $q="insert into tb_admin(id_admin, nama, alamat, jenis_kelamin, satlat, username, password) values(NULL, '".$_POST['txt_nama']."', '".$_POST['txt_alamat']."', '".$_POST['cmb_jeniskelamin']."', '".$_POST['txt_satlat']."', '".$_POST['txt_username']."', '".md5($_POST['txt_password'])."')";
                mysql_query($q);
            }
```

but i don't know what wrong , because the page that process athele data are using same coding style like these and it's working perfectly

I am stumped :( I've done searches and have tried many variations but can't seem to pin point my problem,,

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: try adding a space before the `(` (twice) in your sql query. Is NULL an allowed value for the database field id_admin?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error if you remove the column 'id_admin' and the value 'NULL' like: insert into tb_admin(nama,...) values ('".$_POST['txt_nama']."',...)